# Cookie set in middleware not accessable in server component before refresh the whole page

Tags: next.js, jwt, middleware, server-action

## app/middleware.ts

check for the access token and refresh token if access is removed it refresh the session with new token

```
    else if (!access && refresh && device_id && !is_limited_session) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('device_id', device_id);
    const api = await apiRequest('/session-refresh/', 'POST', formData, '_refresh_token');
    const response = NextResponse.next();
    const apiRes = await api.json();
    switch (api.status) {
        case 200:
            const { access, refresh } = apiRes.detail;
            response.cookies.set('_access_token', access, {
                maxAge: OneDay, httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'strict'
            });

            response.cookies.set('_refresh_token', refresh, {
                maxAge: TenDays, httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'strict'
            });
            return response;

        case 403:
            response.cookies.delete('_refresh_token');
            response.cookies.delete('_device_id');
            break;

        case 400:
            if (isSecuredRoute) {
                const url = new URL('/login', req.url);
                return NextResponse.redirect(url);
            }
            return response;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

app/layout.tsx

    const  token  =  getCookies("_access_token")


getCookie

    export  const  getCookies  = (name:  string) => {

    const  cookiesStore  =  cookies()

    if (cookiesStore.has(name))

    return  cookiesStore.get(name)?.value

    }

still unable to get cookie in layout.tsx that i updated in middleware.ts
```

i want to get updated cookie in my server component without refresh cookie get updated at devtool but server component is not able to process it

Comment: I believe that you can't do this. As the middleware is part of the same request, the cookies would is set only after the first response and it already has gone to the server component.